# How much time is needed to get a spawn from brand new Pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a rural area, a really bad place to play Pokemon Go.
But recently a random level 40 guy offered to submit some new Pokestops in the nearby (post office, city hall..) and after less than a week I finally have 3 pokestops and a gym.

The only problem is that random Pokemon are not spawning yet. Just one sometimes from the sightings.
How much time do I have to wait to have normal Pokemon spawning?

Comment: Not an answer, but [some reports](https://reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/bkpw8k/new_pokestops_have_no_spawn/) say they go months without seeing a spawn :/

Comment: @Wondercricket well, more or less is what I was looking for. Let's wait then...

Comment: Also not an answer, but I have seen Pokestops spawn at areas already with Pokemon spawning around them. When it came to Nearby, they just moved some from the Pokemon that were recorded on a different but close-by Pokespot to the new one, without creating new spawns. I suspect that the spawn process is unrelated to the Pokestop process.

Comment: @MBorg I checked OpenStreetMap (Pokemon Go gets geo data from it) and it seems that many spawn-related items are not present in my area, such as paths, walkways, that's why no Pokemon spawns were moved near the pokestops. I added them by myself, now I only have to wait for a PoGo map update.
The downside is that they can occur at a random time, usually with many months between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may vary: it can happen the same day or several weeks later.
In my case, **4 months**.

Today, I don't know why, Pokemon started to spawn near my house.

Comment: I wonder if it happens whenever Niantic rotates spawns; which is every couple of months and at undisclosed times. I recently moved and there were absolutely no spawns until today

Comment: Niantic recently announced an [update to spawn points](https://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/communitynote-niantic-encounters/) - "… Locations where Pokémon can be found could change as often as every month, …"  Though this may not necessarily be related to new pokestops and associated spawn points.

Comment: @Jerry you solved the mystery, thank you